# How to create submenu dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, menu, flutter-layout, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am working on sidebar in flutter, I need to add a submenu to the alreay existing menu Items.

I have two files, menu_items.dart and sidebar.dart.
Menu_Items codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuItem({Key key, this.icon, this.title, this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);
  final IconData icon;
  final String title;
  final Function onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              icon,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 20,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                fontSize: 15,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how I am using it in Sidebar.dart:

```
   MenuItem(
      icon: Icons.sensor_window,
      title: 'Sensor Parameters',
      ),
```

The thing is, I need to make the sensor parameter

[image]

a parent dropdown, with a list of menu items that I already have. The sub-menu dropdown Items are:

```
TemChartClickEvent,
 HumChartClickEvent,
 MoisChartClickEvent,
 PhChartClickEvent,
 NurChartClickEvent,
 GasChartClickEvent,
```

Which are created using bloc patterns.
The parent menu:

```
MenuItem(
      icon: Icons.sensor_window,
      title: 'Sensor Parameters',
      ),
```

I have been sourcing the internet to get a good resource and make up the menu, but, I couldn't get it to work.

Anyone can help me set it up, giving that I already have MenuItem code above, how do I fit in another bunch of codes call DropDownMenu with its functions, and then pass it into the parent menu, "MenuItem" code above

Answer (score 2):

You have pass ExpansionTile Widget Or Used [multilevel_drawer package](https://pub.dev/packages/multilevel_drawer)

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
  ExpansionTile(
  title: Text("Expansion Title"),
    children: <Widget>[Text("children 1"), Text("children 2")],
  )
 ],
 ),
);
```

Comment: Now that I have my MenuItem class, how do I fit in the MLMenuItem with subMenuItems without conflicting with mine?

Comment: Try `MenuItem(
      icon: Icons.sensor_window,
      title: 'Sensor Parameters',
      ),`
replace by text widget inside children of expansiontile

Comment: I am getting this error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#25c5c relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: Try to add your MenuItem inside Expanded or Flexible Widget like as 
`Expanded(child:MenuItem(icon: Icons.sensor_window,title: 'Sensor Parameters',),),`