# How to create multiple dropdown dropdown in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a seperate DropDown List for teacher name , class name and subject name. How can we do it?. I have written a code but it does not change dynamically while the name changes. I have included both my json response and dropdown code.

Here is my json response:

```
{
"status": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success"
},
"data": {
    "message": "Fetched",
    "details": {
        "response": [
            {
                "teacher_id": "2222",
                "teacher_name": "abc",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "session_id": "123",
                        "class_id": "123",
                        "batch_id": "123",
                        "curriculum_id": "123",
                        "subjects": [
                            "123"
                        ],
                        "subject_details": [
                            {
                                "sub_id": "12222",
                                "sub_name": "science"
                            }
                        ],
                        "class_name": "10",
                        "batch_name": "D"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I have written a code but it does not change dynamically while the name changes.
here is my code:

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: Container(
              child: DropdownButton(
                  value: teacherListSelected,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: const Text(
                    'Teacher',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.teacherListSelected = newVal;
                      print(teacherListSelected);
                    });
                  },
                  items: teacherList?['response']
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Text(item['teacher_name']),
                      value: item['teacher_id'],
                    );
                  }).toList()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: Container(
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: teacherClassSelected,
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: const Text(
                  'class',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.teacherClassSelected = newVal;
                    print(teacherClassSelected);
                  });
                },
                items: teacherList?['response'][1]['details']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    child: Text(item['class_name']),
                    value: item['class_name'],
                  );
                }).toList()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: Container(
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: teacherSubjectSelected,
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: const Text(
                  'subject',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ), items: [],
                // onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                //   setState(() {
                //     this.teacherListSelected = newVal;
                //     getTeacherData();
                //     print(teacherListSelected);
                //   });
                // },
                // items: teacherList?['data']
                //     .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                //   return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                //     child: Text(item['teacher_name']),
                //     value: item['teacher_id'],
                //   );
                // }).toList()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: If you get data from API and display it into the drop-down refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68735915/13997210) and you can display drop-down menu inside other drop-down refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68280926/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil, I want to create a dependent dropdown from the same api response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important things here:

1. You have to save the **array index of selected teacher and class** as well, because this is how you can easily set the dependent dropdown items.
2. You have to make sure you **maintain consistency when selection changes**. For example, if a class is already selected, and then another teacher is selected, it is important set the class selection to `null`, otherwise it would point to a class of another teacher, and Flutter would throw an error because this is no more in the dropdown value set.

Here is the code I think will work for, I made some assumptions, so maybe have to adjust it a little bit. I assume `teacherList` contains the values you posted like this:

```
final teacherList = (<String, dynamic>{
  "status": {"code": 200, "message": "Success"},
  "data": {
    "message": "Fetched init data",
    "details": {
      "response": [
        {
          "teacher_id": "2222",
          "teacher_name": "teacher 1",
          "details": [
(and so on)
```

Please find some comments in the code below:

```
// depending on Flutter version could be String?
Object? _teacherListSelected;
Object? _teacherClassSelected;
Object? _teacherSubjectSelected;
// these are the indexes of selected teacher / class
int? _teacherListSelectedIndex;
int? _teacherClassSelectedIndex;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("My App"),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(children: [
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: Container(
              child: DropdownButton(
                  value: _teacherListSelected,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: const Text(
                    'teacher',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (Object? newVal) {
                    setState(() {
                      _teacherListSelected = newVal;
                      // here we set the selected teacher's
                      // index in array as a number
                      _teacherListSelectedIndex =
                          int.parse(newVal.toString());

                      // every time a teacher is selected,
                      // set every other selection to null
                      _teacherClassSelected = null;
                      _teacherClassSelectedIndex = null;
                      _teacherSubjectSelected = null;
                    });
                  },
                  items: teacherList['data']['details']['response']
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Text(item['teacher_name']),
                      // value will be the selected teacher's index
                      // in the array, stored as string
                      value: teacherList['data']['details']['response']
                          .indexOf(item)
                          .toString(),
                    );
                  }).toList()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: Container(
              child: DropdownButton(
                  value: _teacherClassSelected,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: const Text(
                    'class',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (Object? newVal) {
                    setState(() {
                      _teacherClassSelected = newVal;
                      // here we save selected class array index
                      _teacherClassSelectedIndex =
                          int.parse(newVal.toString());
                      // set subject selection to null
                      _teacherSubjectSelected = null;
                    });
                  },
                  // if teacher is not selected, this list has to be empty
                  items: _teacherListSelected == null
                      ? null
                      // this is the part where class list is depending on
                      // selected teacher
                      : teacherList['data']['details']['response']
                              [_teacherListSelectedIndex]['details']
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            child: Text(item['class_name'] +
                                " " +
                                item['batch_name']),
                            // this is the index of the selected class
                            value: teacherList['data']['details']['response']
                                    [_teacherListSelectedIndex]['details']
                                .indexOf(item)
                                .toString(),
                          );
                        }).toList()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: Container(
              child: DropdownButton(
                  value: _teacherSubjectSelected,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: const Text(
                    'subject',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (Object? newVal) {
                    setState(() {
                      _teacherSubjectSelected = newVal;
                    });
                  },
                  // if class is not selected, subject list will be empty
                  items: _teacherClassSelected == null
                      ? null
                      // this is the part where subject list is depending on
                      // selected class
                      : teacherList['data']['details']['response']
                                  [_teacherListSelectedIndex]['details']
                              [_teacherClassSelectedIndex]['subject_details']
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            child: Text(item['sub_name']),
                            value: item['sub_id'],
                          );
                        }).toList()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  );
}
```